# Rmarkdown ioslides - Allow parametized argument in logo YAML

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown

Is it possible to parametize the logo in a ioslides markdown document?

```
params:
  logo_path: "logo_path"
title: "title"
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    logo: "`r params$logo_path`"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible (at least for now) to use the `params` object in the YAML metadata, but here is a workaround. You can copy the file specified in `params$logo_path` to a fixed file path (assuming it is okay to overwrite this file), e.g.,

````
---
params:
  logo_path: "custom-logo.png"
title: "title"
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    logo: "logo.png"
---

```{setup, include=FALSE}
file.copy(params$logo_path, "logo.png", overwrite = TRUE) 
```
````

Again, I'm assuming it is okay to overwrite the file `logo.png`. The idea is to use a fixed path (e.g., `logo.png`) for the `logo` argument of `ioslides_presentation()`, but dynamically copy the file specified in `params$logo_path` to this fixed path.